# Java: load and edit properties file on classpath

Tags: java, properties, classpath

I would like to persist some properties to property-file in case they were changed during a program run. Now I am trying to do so:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("classpath:app.properties")) {
        properties.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }

    properties.setProperty("word", "abc");

    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("classpath:app.properties")) {
       properties.store(out, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, I tried to do the same, and noticed that my properties wasn't  actually loaded. I couldn't get props I've defined in the file.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to read and write properties file, which are in the `resources` folder (in standard maven project structure) you can use this:

```
// of course, do not forget to close the stream, after your properties file has been read.
properties.load(Runner.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties"));
```

After you modified the properties file, you can use something like:

```
Runner.class.getClassLoader().getResource("app.properties").getFile()
```

to get absolute path to you file.

P.S. Just to be sure you're checking correct file. You shouldn't check file that is in your `resources` folder. The modified file will be placed in the root folder with you classes, like `target` or `out`.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in the same directory as your program, you don't need the classpath part.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("app.properties")) {
    properties.load(in);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("", e);
}

properties.setProperty("word", "abc");

try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("app.properties")) {
   properties.store(out, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("", e);
}
```

Otherwise if the file is within your jar, you would have to repackage the jar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to properties file handling through class path - you can certainly use below code as it is , i think it is simplest way of handling file in class path for both - reading and writing purpose

```
try{

    InputStream in =   this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/suggest.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    in.close();


    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/suggest.properties");
    File fileObject = new File(url.toURI());

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileObject);

    props.setProperty("country", "america");
    props.store(out, null);
    out.close();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```